# Can I assign variables inside a react 'render' statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple columns of data on several rows. For every data element I have a react element. There could be anywhere between 4 and 6 elements on the first row.
For example I display the user's name, birthday and email. If the user entered optional information, I display that as well.
So for another user I might display name, birthday, email, phone number and state.
To not mess up the layout I need to calculate the start and end column of the data, so that the first element (name) fills the layout.

I can make inline calculations inside the return statement, but for abstraction purposes I would like to have a function return the start and end column. I would like to save it in a variable for each row. like this:
`{({ start, end } = getStartEnd(2, this.props))}
 <ColumnSpan row={1} start={start} end={end}>`

That gives error `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {start, end}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

If I use an array `[start, end] = ...` react somehow puts the numbers all over (as if the statement was executed and the variables rendered instead of kept for the next statement).

Comment: Your `render()` function can do whatever you want before returning the JSX that makes up the element. It's easily possible to determine start and end of each row, put it in an array, then return JSX that incorporates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not meaningful JSX. You can spread the props in like this

```
<ColumnSpan row={1} {...getStartEnd(2, this.props)} />
```

You can read some more about spreading props into JSX [here](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/07bbe37bc42b6d4aef81#spread-attributes).

Comment: will that come up with a `start={start} end={end}` by itself or would I have to `start={getStartEnd(2, this.props).start} end={getStartEnd(2, this.props).end)}` ?

Comment: this will do it (no extra work). have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/07bbe37bc42b6d4aef81#spread-attributes

Comment: Amazing. I keep screwing myself by assuming things have to be more complicated than they are .... (as they would be in C)....

Comment: You are welcomed! Glad I could help. If you consider this solved, could you mark it please ;)